# How to continue running a program until I type a specific string?

Tags: python

#This is the program I am writing. I want it to continue until I press "n". But it just works one time. Any answer would be appreciated.

```
names = ["Steve"]

add = input("Enter your name: ")
names.append(add)

ques = input("Do you want to add more? (Press 'y' for yes and 'n' for no)")


if(ques == "y"):
    add = input("Enter your name: ")
    names.append(add)
    print(*names, sep="\n")

elif(ques == "n"):
    print("Program Stopped")

else:
    print("Entered wrong letter!")
```

Comment: You want some kind of [loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming)?

Comment: @khelwood Yes! I am still a beginner, So I am having a hard time doing it.  But for loop should work but idk how to useit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **infinite while loop** for that, Make sure to `break` the **infinite** **loop** once you are in `elif` or `else` block,  also I optimize case sensitive comparison, cause end user may press `Y` not `y`, similarly for `n` and `N'.

**Code :**

```
while True:
    names = ["Steve"]

    add = input("Enter your name: ")
    names.append(add)

    ques = input("Do you want to add more? (Press 'y' for yes and 'n' for no)")


    if ques == "y" or ques =='Y':
        add = input("Enter your name: ")
        names.append(add)
        print(*names, sep="\n")

    elif ques == "n" or ques =='N':
        print("Program Stopped")
        break

    else:
        print("Entered wrong letter!")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you your answer, but this isn't what I want. It just asks max 3 names, I want it as many as I want until I press "n".

Comment: I ran the above code, and I can add as many as I want.

Comment: Yeah it works like that but It doesn't print more than 3 names. I mean if I type "y" then it resets the previous names.

Comment: `while`, `if` and `elif` are not functions, so they don't need the parentheses.

Comment: @Matthias : sure things, I can remove them, I copied from OP so I forgot to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

A `while True` loop is the way to go here. This loop will run forever until you break from it and in this case we use `break` if the user doesn't want to add more names.

```
names = ["Steve"]

while True:
    names.append(input("Enter your name: "))

    # make sure only "n" or "y" is entered
    while True:
        continue_input = input("Do you want to add more? (Press 'y' for yes and 'n' for no)")
        continue_input = continue_input.lower()
        if continue_input in {'y', 'n'}:
            break  # answer is OK, leave the inner loop
        print("Entered wrong letter!")

    # leave the outer loop
    if continue_input == 'n':
        break

    print(*names, sep="\n")

print("Program Stopped")
```

I added a second inner `while True` loop to check if there was a correct answer to the question "Do you want to add more?".

---

Since an other answer got this wrong: Make sure that you set `names = ["Steve"]` before entering the loop and  not in the loop. Otherwise `names` will be reset during each run of the loop.